# Django model clean and ManytoMany problem

Tags: django, django-models

I want to check my Foo instance if it belongs to a category yet my category is a many to many attribute thus I get `"'Foo' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used."` once I try such:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Movie (models.Model):
    poster = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category) 

    def clean(self):
            try:
                self.categories.all().get(db_name="special")
                self.poster.url = u'/media/special_img.png'
            except Category.DoesNotExist:
                pass
```

Comment: could you please add the command for which you are getting this error..

Comment: @Tom - I'd be willing to bet it's from `self.categories.all()`.

Comment: @Dominic: I'd bet you will win this bet

Comment: exactly, using self.categories.all()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check if `Foo` belongs to a category yet until you save it. But since it isn't saved anyway, you can be sure that it doesn't belong to a category yet.

One way to check wheter it has been saved already is by using `if foo.pk`. The `pk` is the primary key and it will be `None` if it hasn't been saved yet.